# Tomcat WAR deployment creates a 404

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, tomcat7

I use the Tomcat Manager to deploy. Whenever I make a website change and compile a new `.WAR` (called `home.war`) and deploy it, I get a **404 Error** when I load my root URL.

Properly configured, http://schmud.de should load http://schmud.de/home/.

The key fact: *if I reboot the Tomcat instance, the deployment will work properly.* How can I avoid this? Here is the `server.xml`'s `<host>` configuration:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false">

  <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->

  <!-- <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" /> -->

  <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->

  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" 
            prefix="localhost_access" suffix=".log" rotatable="false"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

  <Context path="" docBase="home" debug="0" reloadable="true" />

</Host>
```

I’m on Apache Tomcat/7.0.42, JVM 1.7.0, Linux 2.6.32. It’s a cPanel machine.

Edit: After a long delay, I rebuilt the Tomcat machine locally so I have full access to all the parameters. Here are my logs displaying the error when I undeploy and then redeploy the same application, resulting in the 404 error:

`tomcat7/localhost.2016-02-14.log`, undeploy and redeploy -

```
Feb 14, 2016 1:04:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: undeploy: Undeploying web application at '/home'
Feb 14, 2016 1:05:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
Feb 14, 2016 1:06:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
```

`tomcat7/catalina.2016-02-14.log` from undeploy to redeploy -

```
Feb 14, 2016 1:05:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig undeploy
INFO: Undeploying context [/home]
Feb 14, 2016 1:05:03 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader modified
SEVERE:     Resource '/WEB-INF/lib/args4j-2.0.26.jar' is missing
Feb 14, 2016 1:05:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [] has started
Feb 14, 2016 1:05:03 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Feb 14, 2016 1:05:03 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [New I/O  worker #1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Feb 14, 2016 1:05:03 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.ThreadLocalBoolean] (value [com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider$ThreadLocalBoolean@288f896e]) and a value of type [java.lang.Boolean] (value [false]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Feb 14, 2016 1:05:03 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.jboss.netty.util.CharsetUtil$1] (value [org.jboss.netty.util.CharsetUtil$1@6e49414c]) and a value of type [java.util.IdentityHashMap] (value [{US-ASCII=sun.nio.cs.US_ASCII$Encoder@6e14afdd}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Feb 14, 2016 1:05:03 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.ThreadLocalBoolean] (value [com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider$ThreadLocalBoolean@288f896e]) and a value of type [java.lang.Boolean] (value [true]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Feb 14, 2016 1:05:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/home does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:5089)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5269)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3988)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Feb 14, 2016 1:05:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
SEVERE: Exception starting Context with name []
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3988)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Error in resourceStart()
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5270)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 8 more

Feb 14, 2016 1:05:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [] is completed
Feb 14, 2016 1:06:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/home.war
```

The errors are clearly illustrated above, but I'm not well-versed enough with Tomcat to understand them.

Comment: how does your webapps/ look? Did you remove ROOT.war before you deploy? Have you checked your logs what happens while redeploy?

Comment: @Jan - The ROOT.war was removed. After a long delay, I have added the logs above. There is clearly an error. I'm not sure what to do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say you reboot the server do you mean the tomcat instance or the box itself? Tomcat instance reboot should be done when deploying a new version in my experience.  It would be more beneficial to write up a deployment script to save time when doing this.

Comment: I mean rebooting the Tomcat instance. The problem with rebooting Tomcat is that I do not have the privileges to do that. I have to make an admin request, even if the update is trivial. I'm hoping to avoid that.

Comment: You have to reboot the tomcat instance for your changes to take effect.

Comment: that's disappointing. I would love to have a better understanding of why redeploying one .war with the exact same .war would cause this.

Comment: Well the server is always running so it already has application running, best I can figure is that it's somehow cached. Now there is a documented way to get this going but my team was not able to get it to work and our project management wouldn't allow time to figure it out since restarting the server took virtually no time to do.  It would also have added to confusion for maintenance in case the changes didn't take effect; I highly recommend sticking with the reboot that way you know for sure that the changes are in but if you'd like to bubble this up to your middleware team they might do it

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deploying_on_a_running_Tomcat_server

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to follow up on this!